# Imports in yarn monorepo are suggested correctly but not entered when selected

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, hadoop-yarn

So I've seen a lot of people asking similar questions, but in my case, it is a little different and I can't find anyone else having the same.

In my case, when i try to import a component from another workspace, for example, I'm currently working on a file under packages/frontend/client, let's say packages/frontend/client/src/components/NavBar.tsx, and i want to import a component from packages/frontend/lib/src/components/LibButton/index.tsx.

When i write  in the client component, and press Ctrl+Space i get a corrrect suggestion for it saying `LibButton     @goe/lib`, but when i select this option, with Enter or a click, the import is not inserted in the code.
Another weird thing is that when i try to select this line, nothing is inserted but the changes indicator appears next to the title, as if there were changes but obviously nothing is there.

Do you have any ideas what can cause this?

UPDATE:
I found this while checking the window output for errors

```
2024-02-21 13:41:49.596 [error] <semantic> TypeScript Server Error (5.3.3-sdk)
Debug Failure.
Error: Debug Failure.
    at getAutoImportSymbolFromCompletionEntryData
```

So it kinda looks like typescript is not handling the yarn-2 monorepos properly and i haven't found any info online suggesting even some kind of workaround :/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up "fixing" this by having two separate tsconfig files, the default tsconfig.json that is used by vscode where i just added the path to the other packages from where i want to import things, like this: `"include": ["src", "../", "../../common/"]`

And then, because this breaks the build, i added an extra exclusion in the tsconfig.build.json file like

```
"exclude": [
    "**/*.test.ts*",
    "src/testing",
    "../../common/",
    "../lib",
    "../graphql"
  ]
```